# Resizing facebook like button?

Tags: css, facebook, button, facebook-like

can i make facebook like button. smaller. can i scale it somehow with css?

Comment: Are you using FBML or iframes?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firefox, you can add the Greasemonkey plugin, which will allow you to override CSS on any site, including Facebook.

Here's a good [article on the basics](http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/patterns/add-css.html) of adding CSS with Greasemonkey. And here's [another article for CSS noobs](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/greasemonkey-beginners).